# Protocol Handlers in Chrome via Registry

Tags: windows, browser, google-chrome, protocols

For purposes of learning I have created an application which returns a computed output with HTTP protocol. To test that i'm calling in a web browser (IE, FF, Chrome) host with a port:
127.0.0.1:8764. This works on all of the web browsers that were listed earlier. Now i wanted to change the protocol handler to make my application more complex. So I have added a .reg with information about my 'unique' protocol called ProtocolDemoTest. Now when I want to run my application with following URL: ProtocolDemoTest:// I'm getting positive results only on IE and FF, but it seems to somehow fail on Chrome. I have searched a little and only found this http://www.google.fi/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=4e79db1b44daa2e6&hl=en which I find not exactly as i imagined. I want it to work on IE, FF, Chrome with only adding some data into the registry. Can you help me find an actual way to do this in ALL web browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for registerProtocolHandler has now landed in Chrome 13 - http://crbug.com/73710 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The API you're looking for is this one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.navigator.registerProtocolHandler

Though available in Chrome, the call doesn't do anything. This issue tracked here: http://crbug.com/44984

Implementation is underway. See this bug: http://crbug.com/73710

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/navigator.registerProtocolHandler